# How to hide page scroll view during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way we can skip page loading view on the page during page load, but page scroll should happen in background.

our requirement is to scroll the page to some section in the page during page load. but during page load its quick scroll to the section is viewed a Flickr effect.

So is there any chance we can stop showing page scroll during page load but page should be landed in particular section.

Any hack to hide page scroll to overcome page default behavior.

Comment: try doing this... initially make  overflow:hidden and in window.load change it to overflow:auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Try this:***

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(body, html).css('overflow','hidden');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(body, html).css('overflow','auto');
});
```

**or with css:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(body, html).addClass('hideMyScroll');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(body, html).removeClass('hideMyScroll');
});

.hideMyScroll {
overflow: hidden;
}
```